# Problem with footer that only happens on 1 browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello fellow coders I have a website I'm making for a friend and I when I made it and opened it from the html file it looks perfectly normal. When I uploaded it to his web server the footer became white and the sites listed were vertical instead of horizontal.

**Here is what I have tried:**
Going on Microsoft edge worked but I use chrome and chrome doesn't show it like that!
Uploading it again.

**Here is the code and html errors on website:**
http://www.mediafire.com/file/kp9iihyjv120oi8/WEBSTIE.zip/file

[image: HTML Errors]

**Here is what the website looks like on the domain**

[image: Footer On Domain]

**Here is what it looks like when I open the html file**

[image: What it looks like on HTML file]

Thank you!

Comment: The code is in the mediafire link

Comment: Its a file hosting website though

Comment: Ok but can you still help me?

Comment: You're getting an HTTP 404 error from xploit.gq?  Boy, if you can't rely on "xploit.gq", who CAN you rely on? ;)

Comment: Lol im very confused

Comment: yeah, I wouldn't touch the code with a domain like that in it @paulsm4

Comment: So you guys aren't helping me because of the domain?

Comment: that code is 2.66MB!!! Nobody is going to wade through that much code!!!

Comment: The question is unanswerable ... links to code and images are not a "good question"

Comment: @EvanBur - Welcome to SO. Note: You posted a link to an external site with your code. Any relevant code needs to be included here, in your question. Meanwhile, I don't think you're going to have much success calling this site *useless* when you aren't interested in following the guidelines. Nobody should have to go to that site to download your code, and nobody should have to sift through an entire codebase to debug your issue. If you would like help on your issue, I suggest editing your question to include anything relevant, along with any additional info you have , from your debugging work.

Comment: @EvanBur - Also, as you learn more about Stack Overflow, please read this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) which enumerates several reasons why it's very important to include formatted text, instead of images of text. This applies to code, errors, text output, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple, instead of download bootstrap files just add two lines.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

this is the link to more options
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/